# Why is it not possible to access the setup page of a router when using it as a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

If I use  two different router in the same network while both are running in the default router mode then we can access the setup page or setup interface from browser just by IP address of corresponding router. But when I use one of the router as repeater then I can only enter the setup page of the router which is running in router mode. Why router's setup page cannot be accessed when using the router as repeater? Now how can I change the settings of the router in repeater mode? The only way is to reset router with the hardware key then setup again.

Comment: When you turn bridge mode on, the router asks (or recommend) an ip where you can still reach the setup page. If you've forgotten this, hw reset is the easiest way.

Comment: it probably uses a different IP address for each mode - but as you have provided zero details, we can only guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an example that you have 2 routers with IPs of 192.168.0.1 (router A) and 192.168.1.1 (router B). You configure router A to be a repeater for router B (which connects to the internet and has the DHCP server).

Now in *Universal Repeater* mode the router just acts as a **bridge** that relays packets between the 2 network segments. Because the bridge doesn't need to send/receive anything for its own, it generally doesn't need/have an IP in that same subnet with the DHCP (192.168.1.0). You can check this in the DHCP leased list and you won't see the router A there. But router A still has the old IP and still responds to it. It's just that router B doesn't know about the existence of router A, hence it can't route packets to router A even if you use the correct IP address (192.168.0.1) and will just discard the packets.

You need to set your IP address to **static** in the same range of router A, e.g. 192.168.0.2 and now you can access it

You can find some info in these questions

- [ROUTE on Windows - how can I access the router config page without manually setting the IP](https://superuser.com/q/639791/241386)
- [Cannot Access Web GUI after changing to Router mode DD-WRT](https://superuser.com/q/605116/241386)

Answer (score 3):

Some routers allow you to access them while being in repeater mode. However, if you used the same IP for both that will not work. Others however simply repeat everything and turn off any configuration possibility. This is usually the case with No-Name-Devices. Simply reset the repeater, if possible give the device a unique IP OUTSIDE YOUR NETWORK and then you should be able to access it by changing your computers IP.

Example:

Your home network looks like: 192.168.0.0/24 and you set your repeaters IP to 172.16.0.100.

Comment: When you say "outside of your network", wouldn't having it within the subnet but outside the range that is served by DHCP be a better choice? Otherwise you have to set the IP address on the computer trying to access it to 172.16.0.###. If the no-name device doesn't allow any access while in repeater mode, could it still be accessed over wired Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

You can user reverse-ARP to set any IP-Address within you HOST-network to the router's MAC-address.
Then you can connect to that Ip-Address.
Also some router like Tenda, provide a default Hostname to access it in repeater mode.
Chear
NT4 MCSE+I

Comment: What is "reverse-ARP"?